# Unable to create statefulset and PVC in the same AWS AZ

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-statefulset, amazon-eks

Im trying to launch two Cassandra statefulset instances and respective PVC in a cluster created in AWS AZ (Across 3 zones, *eu-west-1a*, *eu-west-1b* & *eu-west-1c*).

I created a node group with the following 2 nodes so as shown these nodes attach in the zones *eu-west-1a* and *eu-west-1b*

```
ip-192-168-47-86.eu-west-1.compute.internal - failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-1a,node-type=database-only
ip-192-168-3-191.eu-west-1.compute.internal - failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-1b,node-type=database-only
```

When I launch the Cassandra instances (using Helm) only one instance starts. The other instance shows the error,

```
0/4 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match node selector, 2 node(s) had no available volume zone.
```

The PVCs for these instances are bounded,

```
kubectl get pvc -n storage -o wide
NAME                            STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
cassandra-data-cc-cassandra-0   Bound     pvc-81e30224-14c5-11e9-aa4e-06d38251f8aa   10Gi       RWO            gp2            4m
cassandra-data-cc-cassandra-1   Bound     pvc-abd30868-14c5-11e9-aa4e-06d38251f8aa   10Gi       RWO            gp2            3m
```

However, the PVs show that they are in zones *eu-west-1b* & *eu-west-1c*

```
kubectl get pv -n storage --show-labels
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                                   STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE       LABELS
pvc-81e30224-14c5-11e9-aa4e-06d38251f8aa   10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound     storage/cassandra-data-cc-cassandra-0   gp2                      7m        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-1b
pvc-abd30868-14c5-11e9-aa4e-06d38251f8aa   10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound     storage/cassandra-data-cc-cassandra-1   gp2                      6m        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-1c
```

I have tried adding the following topology to the `StorageClass` to no avail,

```
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - eu-west-1a
    - eu-west-1b
```

But despite of this I can still see the PVs in the zones, `eu-west-1b` & `eu-west-1c`.

Using K8 1.11.

Any other possible fixes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://v1-11.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/ `allowedTopologies` doesnt exist.

So I used `zones: eu-west-1a, eu-west-1b` in the `StorageClass` which seems to have worked.

```
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  zones: eu-west-1a, eu-west-1b
```